# Put JFrame inside Java3D scene

Tags: java-3d

I would like put a JFrame (JComponent) in a Java3D scene. The JFrame have an animation and the idea is put this component like a texture in a tridimensional box. I read various articles about this subject, but I dont found anyone with this problem. Is possible add JComponent like a texture?

tks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly add a JComponent as a texture.  You can paint your animation into a buffer though and then use that to update your texture.